# How to give a default value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have the following code:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/log_rank/" +  $('#time_filter').text(),
    type: "GET",
    cache: "false",
    success: function(data) {
      rank(data);
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
```

There are times when the following id "`$('#time_filter')`" does not have a value. How do I set this so that whenever this id is null it equals the URL called will be "...../log_rank/all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary operator to define the slug that should be sued as follows:

```
var filterText = $('#time_filter').text(),
    urlSlug    = (filterText == '') ? 'all' : filterText;

$.ajax({
  url: '<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/log_rank/' +  urlSlug,
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) { rank(data); },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With this ternary oparator you can proof the value and decide what to add:

```
($('#time_filter').text() == '' ? 'all' : $('#time_filter').text())
```

implemented in your fragment:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<!--#include virtual="../ include / env"-->/log_rank/" +  ($('#time_filter').text() == '' ? 'all' : $('#time_filter').text()),
    type: "GET",
    cache: "false",
    success: function (data) {
        rank(data);
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, since an empty string is "falsy", you can use the "short-circuited or" operator:

```
var filterText = $('#time_filter').text() || 'all';

$.ajax({
  url: '<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/log_rank/' +  filterText,
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) { rank(data); },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

See also: https://dev.to/flexdinesh/short-circuit-assignment-in-javascript--4k80

Answer (score 0):

You could add a ternary operator in the form:

```
$('#time_filter').text().length > 0 ? $('#time_filter').text() : 'all';
```